# Center text with dynamic TextView size

Tags: android

I have a TextView that is right aligned in a list item. Its background is a drawable, which is just an oval. This textview serves as a badge, and it needs to be a circle (equal width and height).

I achieve this by running the following code:

```
        textView.setText(badgeCount);
        textView.measure(0, 0);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
        int size = Math.max(textView.getMeasuredWidth(), textView.getMeasuredHeight());
        params.width = size;
        params.height = size;
        badgesCountTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This works except the text is left aligned. My xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
...
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_count_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/black_circle"
        tools:text="45"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How am I supposed to center the text within my badge view? I cannot set a fixed width or height, because that needs to be set dynamically depending on the text size. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: As i understand you are resizing your textview, so its background image will be stretch... Are you using 9patch? If so, please be sure that you have right content positions because that would be effecting center position. And you can remove padding sets on xml if you say gravity center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the TextView to `fill_parent` and set the gravity of the TextView to `center` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
...
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge_count_text_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/black_circle"
    tools:text="45"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>

otherwise, if your TextView is as small as your text, you could not center it easily
```

Comment: The problem is, the badge resizes to fill the entire list item. I want it to only be as big as the text.

Comment: The first way is to use margins and paddings, but this won't work for every device. The second way is to put the TextView into a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout which will have the gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

You've set the textview size to wrap content in width and height.  That means the view is extremely small-  just the size of the text.  So it is centered.  What you probably want is to either set its width to fill_parent, or to set its layout_leftAlign and rightAlign or toLeftOf and toRightOf such that it ends up with a larger size.  But without knowing the rest of your layout and what you want it to look like we can't help you.